# links in docker-compose not working with IBM bluemix

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, docker-compose

I've got a link between two containers.
This works fine on local docker.
I've seen two things happening in Bluemix:

1. When using with Bluemix from the CLI my second container is coming up without any of the links in /etc/hosts.  So this container fails to run its processes.
2. The second container starts with a link in /etc/hosts but it takes some time before it can connect, ping does not work for a few minutes.

Is there some latency in container creation process in Bluemix that's causing this ?

Comment: Could you please add your docker-compose file and also the output of `cf ic info | grep Environment`?